# Convert cheerio object to string

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, coffeescript, cheerio

I am extracting metatags from page:

```
$ = cheerio.load(html)
metaTags = $('meta')
```

and it works fine, but I need that **metaTags** array contain strings - not objects of cherrio, like here:

> ["<'meta something=1231'><'/meta'>", "<'meta sometag=44242'><'/meta'>"]

p.s. I dont need ' character it just stackoverflow.com missunderstaning

I have made such , method:

```
toHtml = (el) ->
  return el.html()
```

but it doesnt work : getting empty results (using map with it)

> metaTags.map (i, el) ->
>         console.log  i.toHtml(el)

Comment: `html()` return the content of the first element of a JQuery object.

Comment: In fact Jquery Object are pretty close to Array but they are not actualy arrays. And the Jquery Object contains DOMElement object.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin in python it is easy map(str, page.find_all('div'))

Comment: Yes but you are not using python here :-)

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arrayOfHTMLstrings = $('meta').toArray().map( (el, index) => el.toString() );
```

According to [cheerio official doc](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#toarray)

Answer (score 3):

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
var html = 'SOME_HTML_STRING'
var $ = cheerio.load(html)
var htmlString = $.html()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a solution:

```
findMetaTags = (html) ->
  $ = cheerio.load(html)

  metatagsContainer = $('<p>')
  $('meta').each ->
    metatagsContainer.append $(this).clone()

  unless _.isEmpty(metatagsContainer)
    return metatagsContainer.html()

  return
```

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with all of the answers here.

`myNode.html()` didn't find `html()` method in a lot of cases I tried. `myNode.toString()` returned `[object Object]`.

What finally worked every time was using the html() method on the cheerio itself.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
cheerio.html( myNode )
```

This will convert any node to html string, in a loop or otherwise.

Comment: As per other answer, this should be myNode.html()